# C: Array of automatic storage class?

Tags: c

I'm reading *C How to Program* and I have a question about *storage classes* of arrays. In the book it says:

> *Array and structs are "static" entities in that they remain the same size throughout the program execution (they may, of course, be **of automatic storage class** and hence created and destroyed each time **the blocks** in which they're defined are entered and exited)*

I'm not sure about what *blocks* mean, my current understanding is that function/for/while are blocks. I've tried the following:

```c
...
for (size_t i=1; i<=2; i++) {
    printf("round %c:", i+'0');
    int a[10];
    show_array(a, 10); // this is a function that prints all elements of `a`.
    for (size_t j=0;j<10;j++) {
        a[j]=8;
    }
}
```

I got the output:

```
round 1:0,0,0,0,-1160480784,22023,-1160481168,22023,1594487680,32766,
round 2:8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
```

It seems like `int a[10]` is static, and not **automatic storage class**, am I missing something? (I understand the four storage classes)

I used [ideone.com](https://ideone.com) to run my test, if you need this information.

Comment: What do you think "automatic storage class" means?

Comment: @FredLarson: I think it means the value of the variable, in my case the entire array, would be reset to some uninitialized values. So the second time the for-loop entered `a` will not remember those `8` assigned to it?

Comment: *It seems like `int a[10]` is static* You make this conclusion based on what exactly?

Comment: @n.m.: I edited my comment above.

Comment: Are `32766` or `-1160481168`  "unitialised values"? If they are, why `8` isn't?

Comment: We have very good evidence that the array does not have static storage duration—anything with static storage duration is initialized to 0 at the start of the program, unless you initialize it to something else. Since your array contains garbage numbers like -1160480784, it cannot have static storage duration (unless your program has memory errors somewhere else).

Comment: Per C 2018 6.8.2 2, a compound statement is a block. A compound statement is a pair of braces, `{` and `}`, with declarations and/or statements inside it.

Comment: it's not static unless it has the `static` keyword before it ...

Comment: The “static” in the text you quote is describing a different property (size), not storage duration. Ignore it when considering whether storage duration is static, automatic, or something else. (It is also not a completely correct statement; C has variable-length arrays.)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: The question is about static storage duration, and there are objects with static duration that are not defined or declared with `static`.

Comment: @n.m.: I thought that they're what I just assigned in. Thank you sir I just realized my mistake from the answer below, too many comments/answers I'm still reading.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: You're right and it makes sense. I should not say I understand storage class because I forgot this fact you pointed out...

Comment: @EricPostpischil: So for a *for-loop*, each iteration can be seen as a compound statement, and two distinct iterations are different compound statements thus of different block? Just for a check.

Comment: @user7813604: When execution of a block ends, the lifetime of each object with automatic storage duration associated with that block ends. When another execution of the block begins, each such object created in it has a new lifetime. Every iteration is different.

Comment: 8 is the uninitialized value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are indeed missing something. `a` does have automatic storage, and the values that are printed are a consequence of the memory being re-used, **not** of the storage being persistent. The values will be reset in debug mode (perhaps not by all development environments, but some will set the members to 0xCCCCCCCC *on each iteration*). Also, good compilers (most compilers, if you enable all warnings) will tell you that you're using uninitialized data here.

If you still don't believe me, try this example. It will show that the memory values in `a` are overwritten by the values stored in `b`. The array `a` ceases to exist at the end of the `if` statement's dependent block of code, and all of that memory is made available to the system. On the next iteration, it will probably be used for array `b`, which is why you'll see values of 8 printed in array `b`, even though they were assigned to `a`.

```
for (size_t i=1; i<=2; i++)
{
    if( i&1 )
    {
        printf("round %c:", i+'0');
        int a[10];
        show_array(a, 10);
        for (size_t j=0;j<10;j++) a[j]=8;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("round %c:", i+'0');
        int b[10];
        show_array(b, 10);
        for (size_t j=0;j<10;j++) b[j]=888;
    }
}
```

For a final confirmation that memory is being re-used, you could modify `show_array` to print the raw pointer passed in, not just the individual elements. You should see the same address each time.

Comment: Is that when the array `a` be automatic storage, it mean the array itself is automatic or the elements in the array be automatic?

Comment: An array has the same storage class as the elements inside it (how would an element inside an array outlive the array?)

Comment: What @DietrichEpp said. I'll add  anote to the answer

Comment: @DietrichEpp: oh I got it!

Comment: Thank you sir I do believe you but it's just my style of asking.

Answer (score 4):

"Automatic storage class" refers to the scope in which the variable is defined. It means that the memory allocated to the variable will be freed upon exiting the scope in which the variable was created, not that the memory will be initialized for you. You still have to do that yourself. The reason you see the 8s in the second iteration of your loop is because the same memory that was freed in the previous iteration was reassigned to the array.

Answer (score 3):

The array `a` is an **automatic** variable because it is defined in a block scope, the block in this case being the body of the `for` loop.  The fact that you see the values you set the last time doesn't mean the variable is static.

Automatic variables are **uninitialized** if not explicitly initialized.  This basically means they'll contain whatever happened to be in those memory locations the last time they were used.

On the first iteration of the loop, you see seemingly random values in the array.  The variable then goes out of scope at the end of the loop, and on the next iteration a new instance is created, but in this case it happened to be created at the same memory location it was created at last time, and nothing else happened to write to that memory location, so you end up seeing the same values.  There's no guarantee that you'll see the same behavior if you for example make an unrelated code change or compile with different optimization settings.

Answer (score 2):

When the lifetime of an object with automatic storage duration ends, that just means the memory is released (so that it may be used for other purposes). It does not guarantee that the memory is erased or that it is used for other purposes.

When the lifetime of another instance of the same object begins, memory is allocated for it again. It may happen to be the same memory that was used for it before. There is no guarantee that it was erased or used for other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has what is scientifically known as [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In your case it results from using (printing) a bunch of `int` objects before initialising them.

Since the behaviour is undefined, program output can be anything at all, including a stream of characters that could possibly in theory lead someone into believing in an obvious nonsense (like `a` having static storage duration).

In practical terms, this is what happens if you ignore the high-brow world of language standards and look at the *iron*:

- At round 1 `a` contains garbage values, remnants of whatever has been stored at that memory location previously.
- At round 2 `a` still contains garbage values, remnants of whatever has been stored at that memory location previously.

The only difference is that the garbage looks familiar to you, because it happens to be *your* garbage. You can see it because the garbage people did not have a chance to collect it yet. It is still garbage however — the garbage people **will** remove it at some point.