# Deletion on a non pointer array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, delete-operator

When I have an array like this:

```
int* test = new int[50];
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    test[i] = dist4(rng);
}
```

(Filled with random numbers for testing)

I can free the memory like this:

```
delete[] test;
```

But when I declare the array like this:

```
int test[50];
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    test[i] = dist4(rng);
}
```

I can't free the memory with delete or delete[].

What's the proper way of freeing the memory here?

The "dist4" function is just a random number generator:

```
random_device dev;
mt19937 rng(dev());
uniform_int_distribution<mt19937::result_type> dist4(1,4); // distribution in range [1, 4]
```

Comment: No need to free memory explicitly in the latter case.

Comment: You don't need to do anything.  That's the beauty of [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Comment: _"So whats the proper way of freeing the memory here?"_ letting the variable go out of scope.

Comment: Don't use `new`/`delete` like this. Use `std::vector<int> test(50);` instead. It should be your default assumption in C++ that objects will automatically clean up and free memory when they go out-of-scope. Everything else like `new` are special cases and you almost never need or should use `new`/`delete` directly.

Comment: The random number part is probably irrelevant for your question anyways, but shouldn't `one[i]` in the first code snippet be `test[i]`?

Comment: @user17732522 
Using the vector class is good when you programm is not reliant on runtime speed, but the class is very slow.
I used it very heaviely at the start of my current project. After removing it the speed of my simulation doubled and even more for bigger numbers.
using the "new int[] + delete" was a lot faster than "vector<int>". But else you're right\
\
@Manfred 
Yes you're right, it should be ```test[i]```
In my programm it's one but I changed it here for better readability. Must have overlooked. Thank you for pointing out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C: Array of automatic storage class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53382014/c-array-of-automatic-storage-class)

Comment: @FabriceSchöneberger `std::vector` should only be slower in a few rare situations, mainly because `std::vector` by-default zeros the memory, while `new int[...]` doesn't and because `std::vector` stores the allocation size twice. Everything else, like access to the allocated array should compile down to the exact same code. Even if you have a reason to avoid these vector overheads, you should use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` and `std::make_unique_for_overwrite<int[]>(50);` instead of `new`/`delete`.

Comment: @user17732522 
I haven't seen ```std::unique_ptr<int[]>``` or ```std::make_unique_for_overwrite<int[]>(50)``` yet so they might be better, but for ```std::vector``` I can say from testing and from other posts that it is a lot slower than an array (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932222/c-vector-vs-array-time) and from my own testing only I saw that new/delete instead of .push_back() is still faster by a lot. I don't know if it is something about the enviroment or nature of my code but switching to new/delete made it better

Comment: @FabriceSchöneberger Have you read the answer to that question? The point is that `vector<bool>` is different from all other `vector` specializations and indeed that one is generally slower. Also, the question is comparing `vector` to an actual declared array, I was comparing to `new`/`delete`. Yes, `push_back` is slower (especially without a prior `reserve` call), but you don't need to use it. You just need `vector<int> test(50);`, remove the `new`/`delete` lines and that's all. If `vector` is slower for you, it is likely that you are just using it wrong.

Comment: @user17732522 So i rewrote my programm and exchanged all new/delete for vectors and while it did indeed solve my memory problem it did make the programm 3 times slower than before (20-25 min runtime to about 90 min runtime). I don't know if I'm using it wrong and if how but I think it's just slower overall.
PS: ```std::unique_ptr<int[]>``` looks nice but I need a dynamikly sized array. The same reason I'm not using normal arrays from the start. And ```std::make_unique_for_overwrite<int[]>(50)``` was not found by my gpp compiler (11.2.0)

Comment: @FabriceSchöneberger `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` does store a dynamically sized array. `std::make_unique_for_overwrite` requires C++20, but GCC 11.2 supports that. It can be enabled with the `-std=c++20` flag, see https://godbolt.org/z/KWMGxc3Ta. Also note the `-O2` flag. A common mistake is to forget to enable optimizations with that and then any performance measurement is completely pointless. If you can create a [mre] for the performance issue, you can make a question. Just make sure to consider what I said so far before and be open that you might just be misusing the classes.

Comment: @user17732522 ```int test = 50; std::unique_ptr<int[test]> testvalue``` With this my compiler complains that ```test``` has to be constant and ```auto x = unique_ptr<int[]>(50);``` also doesn't work I haven't found a way in the documentation for a way to make it dynamik. For some reason my compiler still does not recognise the ```std::make_unique_for_overwrite``` even with the extra compiler tag. But the ```-O2``` is magic. Code is so much faster now. Before 90 min now 30. The new/delete is also faster from 25 to 17 so hmmm.

Comment: Continues from comment before: I don't know how I can boil down the problem far enouth for a real question yet, but it's not important enouth as my code with the "slower" vector is still fast enouth for now.
Thanks for the help man

Comment: @FabriceSchöneberger `auto x = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<int[]>(test);` produces a `x` of type `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` that is essentially a (pointer to a) dynamic array of `test` uninitialized `int`s. It can be used exactly like such an array and if you need a raw pointer from it you can use `x.get()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's the proper way of freeing the memory here?

No need to free memory explicitly using `delete` or `delete[]` in the latter case.

Assuming `int test[50];` is declared inside a function, it has [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) and when `test` goes out of scope it will be automatically destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

The memory will automatically be freed when it does out of scope like any other non-dynamically allocated variable. This is due to [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Answer (score 0):

Write the code like this using a local scope:

```
void a_function ()
{

  // some code

  {
    int test[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
      test[i] = dist4(rng);
    }
  }
  // here the space for test will recovered.

  // some more code...

}
```